# Events - Timing mechanisms

Tags: nearprotocol

I was wondering if there is a way for a contract to be triggered/called by the blockchain itself
-> maybe another contract **that is not** triggered by users using the near cli or a front end, or maybe be called by an event, or something like that?

For example: let's say a company wants to pay its employees using smart contracts. Ideally, the company only needs to register (and unregister) the employees to the smart contract and store some info like the monthly salary. The smart contract would know when a month ends a new one starts, and it would transfer the salary to the employees all be itself without anyone triggering the transfers.

Is that possible?

If yes, would you please send me a link the learn about it?

If not, why? Is it a future feature, or is it not the way we should think about smart contracts?

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out https://roke.to and https://cron.cat

these two projects, built by the community during hackathons, have something like what you're describing